# Absolute Div Being Clipped with Negative Margin

Tags: html, css, css-float

**EDIT**: I've modified my code and I know have the desired effect in the top left corner but now my content container isn't automatically extending all the way down (has the black background. [JSFIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/cCVjf/embedded/result/)

I've been trying to add a hovering label over a div but it seems to be getting clipped off and I've tried for a few hours to get it working with no success. THe parent is set to relative, and the child is absolute, but whenever I set the child container to overflow: auto, it gets clipped. Here's the js fiddle so you can see what i'm talking about (TEST123 in the top left corner) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PqALH/). I also need the content in the right side container to autogrow the parent div. I'm trying to have the top left corener where it's says TEST123 appear like the "Transport" example:[image]; My attempted result is not cutting off the text when positioning it out on top of the parent div

HTML

```
    <div class="contentcontainer">
        <div class="labels">Test 123</div> 

<div id="instructors">PlaceHOlder</div>
<div id="ccleft">
 <h1 class="orange">Sample</h1>
                        <ul id="instructorbullets">
                            <li>1st Degree Blackbelt</li>
                            <li>Criminal Justice Major</li>
                            <li>Proud Dad of A.J.</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="normal"> lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
<div id="ccright"><div id="ccrightcontainter"><div id="ccrightcontaintertext"><h1 class="blue">About The Instructor</h1><p class="normal"> foo bar baz <br /><br />Lorem baz<br /><br />More text</p></div></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .clear { clear: both:}

    #.labels {
 position: absolute;
 left: -15px;
 top: -15px;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 height: 35px;
 background: #0FF;
 color: #d94a3c;
 font-family: font1;
 font-size: 2.0em;
 z-index: 1;
 clear: both;
}
 #.contentcontainer {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 940px;
 background: #fff;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 overflow:auto;
 clear:both
}
#ccleft {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
#ccright {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 570px;
    float: left;
}
#ccrightcontainter {
    position: relative;
    width: 550px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both
}
#ccrightcontaintertext {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    clear: both
}
```

Comment: why do you have the values of top and left set to -30px?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here... since you're parent div has no left or top value & the div that is "clipped" has left:-30 & top:-30, the div gets positioned 30px outside the viewport. because that's what you've set it up to do in your css ...

Comment: so what do you want @Ovidio can you post your desired result image....

Comment: Updated with the desired effect i'm going for.

Comment: You need the overflow:hidden on your contentContainer to expand it for the child containers.  I edited my answer below to utilise an outerContentContainer that you wrap everything in.  You make your labels div a direct child of the outerContentContainer and then absolutely position it on that.  You are then free to put overflow:hidden on your contentContainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just forked your fiddle to show you a workaround.  Basically I wrapped everything in an outerContentContainer. The labels div is now absolutely positioned as a direct child of the outerContentContainer. You can then add overflow:hidden to your contentContainer.

Seems like a bit of a hack but overflow:hidden or auto will clip your content but you need it in order to auto expand according to child divs

Js fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/a3TvU/2/

```
<div class="outerContentContainer">
<div class="labels">Test 123</div> 
<div class="contentcontainer">
```

and the css is

```
.labels {
    position: absolute;
    top:-30px;
    left:-30px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    height: 35px; 
    background: #0FF;
    color: #d94a3c;
    font-family: font1; 
    font-size: 2.0em;
    z-index: 1;
    clear: both;

}

.contentcontainer { 
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.outerContentContainer{
    position:relative;
}
```

Wing